# Python - Reading line by line from file to Tkinter Text

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter, textbox

I decided I want to do some GUI programming with Python Tkinter,and I wanted to start with a Text Editor.I've written some code and everything seems to be looking fine but I have trouble inserting text to the Text widget.It doesn't insert all lines just a few.Anyone seems to know the answer?I'm starting with Tkinter and I might move to PyQT.I want to use Python 2.7,so please don't post Python 3.x asnwers.Thanks

```
import Tkinter as TK
from tkFileDialog import *

#Callbacks
def clearCallback(event):
    print "Clearing..."
    textBox.delete("1.0",TK.END)
    print "Cleared."
return
def openCallback(event):
    print "Trying to open a file..."
    fname = askopenfile(mode='r',initialdir="C:\\")
    if(fname):
        print str(fname)
        content = fname.readlines()
        print str(content)
        for line in content:
            textBox.insert(TK.END,line)
        fname.close()
        return
    else:
        print "No file was opened."
    return
print "---MiniPyE---"
#Base
base = TK.Tk()
base.resizable(height=False,width=False)
base.minsize(650,600)
base.title("MiniPyE")
#Buttons
#Clear Button
clearButton = TK.Button(base,text="New")
clearButton.place(x=16,y=0,height=16,width=48)
clearButton.bind("<Button-1>",clearCallback)
#Open Button
openButton = TK.Button(base,text="Open")
openButton.place(x=16+48,y=0,height=16,width=48)
openButton.bind("<Button-1>",openCallback)
#Text Box
textBox = TK.Text()
textBox.place(x=16,y=16,height = 684,width=650)
#Scrollbar
scrollBar = TK.Scrollbar(base,command=textBox.yview)
scrollBar.place(x=0,y=0,height=584)
#scrollBar.grid(row=0,column=1,sticky='nsew')
base.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the output, what do you expect?

Comment: I have the code in a file called minipye.py and when I press open I try to read the script itself.But it only reached to this line:

textBox = TK.Text()

Comment: Are you trying to read this same script?

Comment: Yes I am,but it doesn't work for some strange reason

Comment: What makes you think it stops at a particular line? Is that all you see? Is it possible the rest was loaded and just isn't visible because the window is too small?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it.The thing was that the height was too big.I changed:
`textBox.place(x=16,y=16,height=684,width=650)`
to
`textBox.place(x=16,y=16,height=580)`
and everything went fine.Just as expected.

Comment: You should consider _not_ using `place`. Your GUIs will have better behavior if you use `grid` or `pack` with appropriate options. Generally speaking, `place` should only be used for very specific types of problems that can't be easily solved by the other two. Tkinter is exceptionally good at computing the appropriate size for the widgets.